# How to define a Reduce function in order to define two parameters afterwards

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I'm trying to evaluate numerically an equilibrium for a system of ODEs:

```
dA = c A + b B - a A
dB = d B + a A - b B
```

So I define a list of known parameters:

```
parameters={a->1,b->2}
```

But there are other parameters that are still unknown, and I'd like to explore the parameter space afterwards:

```
equil[x_,y_]:=Reduce[{dA==0,dB==0}//.{parameters,c->x,d->y},{A,B}]
equil[5,3]
```

However, I can't manage to define the function in such a way that I can manipulate the still undefined parameters. Thank you in advance!

Comment: On my system your code throws the message "ReplaceRepeated::rmix: Elements of {{a->1,b->2},c->5,d->3} are a mixture of lists and nonlists. >>"  Is this what you need help with or merely incidental?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's what I need help with. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Put `Flatten@` in front of `{parameters,c->x,d->y}`.

Comment: Or do `Join[parameters, {c -> x, d -> y}]` in place of `{parameters,c->x,d->y}`.

Comment: One could also use two `ReplaceAll` expressions: `equil[x_, y_] := 
 Reduce[{dA == 0, dB == 0} /. parameters /. {c -> x, d -> y}, {A, B}]`.  Note that as Jack LaVigne wrote one should not indiscriminately use capital letters in *Mathematica*; for example `C`, and `D` are reserved Symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Using upper case letters for the beginning of a symbol is frowned upon so I am going to replace `A` and `B` with `u` and `v`.

So your equilibrium system becomes:

```
dA = c u + b v - a u
dB = d v + a u - b v
```

Now when we replace `a` with 1 and `b` with 2 we get

```
dA /. {a -> 1, b -> 2}
(* -u + c u + 2 v *)

dB /. {a -> 1, b -> 2}
(* u - 2 v + d v *)
```

Below is the general solution when you equate `dA` and `dB` to zero

```
Reduce[-u + c u + 2 v == 0 && u - 2 v + d v == 0, {u, v}]

(-2 + d != 0 && c == d/(-2 + d) && v == 1/2 (u - c u)) || 
(-2 c - d + c d != 0 && u == 0 && v == 0)
```

To see the results for specific value of `c` and `d` define:

```
equil[c_, d_] := Reduce[-u + c u + 2 v == 0 && u - 2 v + d v == 0, {u, v}]
```

and then apply it

```
equil[5, 3]
(* x == 0 && y == 0 *)
```

another example

```
equil[-1, 1]
(* y == x *)
```